# How do categories of the request? Category -> Sub-Category

Tags: codeigniter

How to do category "tree" with codeigniter? 
I have problem with "$this->db->join('kategorijos', $kategorija['pavadinimas'].'= sub_kategorijos.kategorijos_id');"

```
public function get_categories(){
    $this->db->order_by('pavadinimas');
    $query = $this->db->get('kategorijos');
    return $query->result_array();
}

public function get_sub_categories(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('sub_kategorijos');
    $this->db->join('kategorijos', $kategorija['pavadinimas'].'= sub_kategorijos.kategorijos_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem you obeyed docs' rule: `$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');`. And also you don't have defined `$kategorija['pavadinimas']` in method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do `foreach` in `get_categories` method, then you manipulate the data to integrate with your `get_sub_categories` method. For example:

```
public function get_sub_categories($category_id){
    if(isset($category_id))
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('category_id',$category_id);
        $this->db->from('sub_kategorijos');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function get_categories(){
    $this->db->order_by('pavadinimas');
    $query = $this->db->get('kategorijos');
    $array = $query->result_array();
    $output = [];
    foreach($array as $data)
    {
        $subcategories_data = $this->get_sub_categories($data['category_id']);
        if($subcategories_data)
        {
            $output[$data] = $subcategories_data;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```